# Нормально ли изменять (портить) передаваемый по ссылке объект внутри метода?

Tags: c++, безопасность

В классе синглтоне есть метод который принимает объект класса **SentPackage**, олицетворяющего отправленный пакет. Внутри этого объекта находится довольно крупный вектор **payload**.

```
void PendingStorage::AddPackage(SentPackage& in_packet); // Внутри in_packet огромный вектор payload.
```

В методе **AddPackage** мне необходимо сохранить **in_packet** в **std::map** и тут я встал перед дилеммой. Я могу либо копировать объект либо переместить его (с помощью **std::move**). Во втором случае я довольно сильно выиграю по производительности т.к. в конструкторе копирования **SentPackage** внутренний вектор **payload** также будет перемещаться. Но получается, что **in_packet** во втором случае будет опустошён и далее не пригоден для использования, что конечно я буду учитывать в своём коде. Проблема может возникнуть кода мой синглтон будет использовать другой программист, который не чего не знает об изменениях передаваемого объекта внутри моего метода. По идее на эти изменения будут указывать отсутствие спецификатора const у **in_packet** и мои комментарии которые я напишу=) Но всё же мне кажется это очень небезопасным решением. Меня интересует ваше мнение, на сколько это вообще считается безопасным в нормальном сообществе и как принято разруливать такие ситуации в ваших проектах?

Comment: как правило, если метод не изменяет входной параметр, то этот параметр объявляют константной ссылкой `foo(const int& i)`. Если параметр передается по ссылке, то это означает, что функция МОЖЕТ изменить его. Как правило это оговаривается в документации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принимай r-value, тогда "другой" программис просто так туда не отдаст и будет готов к тому, что объект после этого вызова будет не валиден.

```
void PendingStorage::AddPackage(SentPackage&& in_packet);
```

UPD:
Если вызывается будет так:

```
foo()
{
    SentPackage in_packet;
    pending_storage.AddPackage(std::move(in_packet));
}
```

А в AddPackage будет так:

```
void PendingStorage::AddPackage(SentPackage&& in_packet)
{
     m_packets.empalce(key, std::move(in_packet));
}
```

То компилятор это выродит до 1 перемещения. Причем, если SentPackage(SentPackage&&) написан правильно, то стоимость этого перемещения ничто по сравнению с добавление в std::map

Comment: Я так и сделал вначале, но тогда нам нужно делать два перемещения. А этот участок очень критичен с точки зрения производительности. По сути он сейчас является узким местом всего приложения.

Comment: @mrFieldy Перемещение будет все равно только одно, независимо от количества вызовов `std::move`.

Comment: После перемещения объект остается валидным.

Comment: @VTT объект оставаться валидным не может, т.к. иначе операция move не даст вам выигрыша. Внутри конструктора мув контейнеров идёт просто передача указателя вместо затратных операций аллоцирования и копирования данных. Можете это проверить, переместив вектор или другой контейнер у себя и посмотреть, что у вас останется в исходном. Сейчас проверяю что одиночный вызов move. Если это так то это будет очень круто.

Comment: @mrFieldy Объект обязан оставаться валидным по стандарту. При перемещении объектов `std::vector` исходный вектор после перемещения всегда остается в валидном состоянии. Пустой вектор тоже является валидным состоянием. Поэтому "испортить" объект премещением из него не получится.

Comment: @VVT, не обязан. Это UB

Comment: @VTT вектор внутри моего объекта опустошается, т.к. перемещение контейнера опустошает контейнер откуда происходит перемещение. После такого трудно назвать мой объект валидным. Про один вызов move тоже не сработало, перемещение происходит два раза. Вот код https://godbolt.org/g/FYzVm1. Может я вас как-то неправильно понял?

Comment: Ничего нет неопределенного, стандартом обеспечена строгая безопасность

Comment: @VTT я вас понял. Мы просто по-разному трактовали слово валидный. Я с точки зрения, что в объекте не будет актуальных данных, а вы с точки зрения стандарта. Я согласен с вами что тут вы правы. Но мне от этого не легче. Внутри моего метода объект теряет свои данные и другой программист может об этом не знать. А два перемещения я делать не хочу в виду ухудшения производительности.

Comment: @mrFieldy Пустой объект тоже является валидным. У него можно спокойно вызвать методы и перезаполнить его. Для него следует по-прежнему вызвать деструктор. У невалидного объекта вызов любого метода являлся бы неопределенным поведением. Конструктор перемещения в вашем примере вызывается два раза, так как вы создаете временный объект `std::pair`. [Используйте `emplace`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z27cCBZOhCP5c3Oc).

Comment: @VTT большое вам спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @ mrFieldy, если вы храните что то в каком то хранилище, то какраз нормально, что   сущность, в котором вы раньше хранили это, будет пустым, потому что ваш обьект уже в хранилище.